# PHP PDO fetchColumn not returning result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, pdo

Here is my code:

```
$result = $link->query($query);
//Get query results 

$x = 0; 
$tableA = [];
$tableB = [];


while($tables = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $test[] = $tables; 
    $assoc = $test[$x]; 

    $tableName = $assoc['TABLE_NAME']; 
    $columnName = $assoc['COLUMN_NAME']; 
    $refTableName = $assoc['REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME'];
    $refColumnName = $assoc['REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME']; 

    $fkQueryA = "SELECT DISTINCT " . $columnName . " FROM " . $dbName . "." . $tableName . " ORDER BY ".$columnName." ;"; 
    $fkQueryB = "SELECT DISTINCT " . $refColumnName . " FROM " . $dbName . "." . $refTableName . " ORDER BY ".$refColumnName." ;"; 

    echo $fkQueryA."\n"; 
    echo $fkQueryB."\n"; 

    $resultA = $link->query($fkQueryA);
    $resultB = $link->query($fkQueryB);

    $tableA[] = $assoc['COLUMN_NAME'];
    while($var = $resultA->fetchColumn())
    {
        $tableA[] = $var;
    }

    $tableB[] = $assoc['REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME'];
    while($vari = $resultB->fetchColumn())
    {
        $tableB[] = $vari; 
    }

    $x++; 
}

var_dump($tableA); 
//var_dump($tableB);
```

The code is returning this result when run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT salesRepEmployeeNumber FROM classicmodels.Customers ORDER BY     salesRepEmployeeNumber ;
SELECT DISTINCT employeeNumber FROM classicmodels.Employees ORDER BY     employeeNumber ;
SELECT DISTINCT officeCode FROM classicmodels.Employees ORDER BY officeCode ;
SELECT DISTINCT officeCode FROM classicmodels.Offices ORDER BY officeCode ;
SELECT DISTINCT orderNumber FROM classicmodels.OrderDetails ORDER BY orderNumber ;
SELECT DISTINCT orderNumber FROM classicmodels.Orders ORDER BY orderNumber ;
SELECT DISTINCT productCode FROM classicmodels.OrderDetails ORDER BY productCode ;
SELECT DISTINCT productCode FROM classicmodels.Products ORDER BY productCode ;
SELECT DISTINCT customerNumber FROM classicmodels.Payments ORDER BY customerNumber ;
SELECT DISTINCT customerNumber FROM classicmodels.Customers ORDER BY customerNumber ;
array(545) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "salesRepEmployeeNumber"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "officeCode"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [5]=>
  .....and so on.
```

`fetchColumn()` is returning the proper results for all the other columns of my query results, just not that column's worth of information. Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

Data in salesRepEmployeeNumber column:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT salesRepEmployeeNumber FROM classicmodels.Customers;                                         +------------------------+
| salesRepEmployeeNumber |
+------------------------+
|                   NULL |
|                   1165 |
|                   1166 |
|                   1188 |
|                   1216 | 
|                   1286 |
|                   1323 |
|                   1337 |
|                   1370 |
|                   1401 |
|                   1501 |
|                   1504 |
|                   1611 |
|                   1612 |
|                   1621 |
|                   1702 |
+------------------------+
```

Comment: Have you considered adding error checking to all of the query functions?

Comment: You're not clearing `tableA` and `tableB` on each iteration of your outer `while`, so it would stand to reason that the `salesRep` query returned **NOTHING**, and then you went on and appened all other field/results from the other queries.

Comment: Jay: I haven't, but will look into it. 
Marc: `salesRepEmployeeNumber` has contents.

Comment: could you post the proof data in`classicmodels.Customers` that we have any `salesRepEmployeeNumber` filled please. By the way yorr code style and logic flow is terrible :-)

Comment: Alex: Added the data to the question. And I'm sure it is, I don't have a lot of experience in PHP coding.

Comment: just a guess, could you get rid of `NULL` value for the moment?

Comment: Alex: I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Not that I am able to explain why this error occurred, but it has been resolved (for now). Deleted the foreign key query echo statements and now the salesRepEmployeeNumber section is showing up. If anyone could venture a guess as to why that is, that would be great.